# Capture and write string inside of dataframe using foreach row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

Trying to capture and write a string value after substituting contents obtained from specific fields from each row of a dataframe using scala. But since it is deployed on cluster not able to capture any records. Can anyone provide a solution?

Assuming TEST_DB.finalresult has 2 fields input1 and input2:

```
val finalresult=spark.sql("select * from TEST_DB.finalresult")

finalResult.foreach { row => 
    val param1=row.getAs("input1").asInstanceOf[String]
    val param2=row.getAs("input2").asInstanceOf[String]

    val string = """new values of param1 and param2 are -> """ + param1 + """,""" + param2
    // how to append modified string to csv file continously for each microbatch in hdfs ??
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you create the wanted `string` variable but it is not being saved anywhere, hence you can't see the result.

You can potentially in each `foreach` execution open up the wanted csv file and append the new string, but I'd like to propose a different solution.

If you can, try to always use built-in functionality of Spark, since it is (usually) more optimised and better in handling null inputs. You can achieve the same by:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, concat, col}

val modifiedFinalResult = finalResult.select(
 concat(
  lit("new values of param1 and param2 are -> "),
  col("input1"),
  lit(","),
  col("input2")
 ).alias("string")
)
```

In variable `modifiedFinalResult` you will have a spark dataframe with single column named `string`, which represents the exact same output as your variable `string` in your code. Afterwards you can save the dataframe directly as a single csv file (using the repartition functionality):

```
modifiedFinalResult.repartition(1).write.format("csv").save("path/to/your/csv/output")
```

PS: Also a suggestion for the future, try to avoid naming variables after data types.

> UPDATE: Fixed the empty rows issue by using "concat_ws" instead of concat and coalesce to each fields. It seems some of the values which were null were transforming the entire concatenated string to null after the transformation. Nevertheless this solution works for now!

Comment: I will check and update if this works! however i would like to add, the string capture is not the only operation i will be doing inside the foreach, there is another function "TopicWriter.save(string, topic2)" which actually produces to a kafka topic. Any suggestion how to club these together ? since I see you suggested creating a new dataframe from old and writing...

PS: my bad about the 'string' var name, i only prepared this to closely resemble my code... :)

Comment: Got it, sorry I assumed by the commented line in your code that you wish to save it as a csv file. Yes then indeed using foreach is the way to go, but I'd still apply the foreach on the `modifiedFinalResult` dataframe, since that action will be more optimised and safer to perform: `modifiedFinalResult.foreach{row => TopicWriter.save(row.getAs[String]("string"), topic2)}`

Comment: that could be done. I will test and see how this performs. Also since these are microbatches , need completed under 1 min, creating another df may add overhead... i will update here. 

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: I tested the approach and it works as expected in spark-shell. However, facing two issues:
1. from spark job topic & hdfs file value is "null" when using modifiedFinalResult. spark-shell gives me correct output when using modifiedFinalResult.show(1,false) 
2. hdfs location creating empty 0 byte files for every microbatch. How to avoid creating empty files or append to the same file ?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using for pushing rows into the topic? Because I can't really see directly why that is happening.

Comment: I am limited to corporate limitations. 
But the hdfs write operation also writes empty if I use:

modifiedFinalResult.repartition(1).write.mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","false").save("/tmp/out/final.data")

also, 2 fields which are being called at the very beginning of the select are populated in the file, but not the concatenated string :
val modifiedFinalResult = finalResult.select(
        col("event_dt"),
        col("event_hr").... 

Is it possible that the dataframe is lost when used once ? or it only works on spark-shell?

Comment: Intriguing. Well no the dataframe is never lost, no matter how many times you use it or write it. If the code works for you in 1 environment and not in the other, I'd suggest taking a look at the configuration and included jars in the environment where the code works well and try to replicate it in the desired execution environment.